# The “import java.util.function cannot be resolved” error

Tags: spring

```
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

strRoles.forEach(new Consumer<String>())
```

How can I write the program without using supplier and consumer in Java JDK 1.7?

Answer (score 0):

`java.util.function.Consumer` and Functional Interfaces in general came in java 1.8,
so you just don't have these packages in java 1.7

Since lambdas are also not supported at the level of language, the only option you have is anonymous inner classes, there is nothing to do with it.

If you're looking only for interfaces, some similar concepts are available in [guava](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/FunctionalExplained)

Comment: .orElseThrow(() -> // could you please tell me how to write an exception with out using orelsethrow(() -> new exception ) for java 1.7 version

Comment: in an imperative way perhaps: if(someCondition) { ..} else {throw new YourException();}